# Plotting points with color and shape based on data variables

Tags: r, variables, colors, plot, shapes

I am trying to make a scatter plot with the colors of each point corresponding to one variable and the shape of each point corresponding to another variable.
Here is some example data and the code I used to make the second plot:

```
Example data:(of 3 points)
 X    Y    att1    att2

.5    .5    1       A
.24   .8    3       B
.6    .7    5       C

code:(for image2)
> plot(X,Y, col=statc[att2], pch = 15)
> legend("right", statv, fill=statc)

Where:
> statv
[1] "A"  "B" "C"  
> statc
[1] "red"    "blue"   "orange"
```

I have done this individually but dont know how to do both. Here is two plots:

## 1[image]

## 2[image]

For example: I want the colors to apply to the points with the same att1 and the shapes to apply to points with the same att2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One of the domain where `ggplot2`  excels , comparing to other R system plots,  is mapping plot parameters to data variables.( via aesthetics mechanism)

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(X =runif(20),
                     Y =runif(20),
                     att1 = gl(5,20/5),
                     att2 =gl(3,20/3))
ggplot(dat,aes(x=X,y=Y,color=att1,shape=att2)) +
    geom_point(size=5)
```

[image]

You can do it in the base plot also, but you should generate manually the legend ...

```
plot(dat$X,dat$Y,pch=as.integer(dat$att1),col=as.integer(dat$att1))
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error for trying to map a continous variable to a shape. However, the variable just takes a small number of different values. Is it still possible somehow to map the varibale to a shape/color with ggplot?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/519) answers my own question: I had to add `+ scale_shape_identity()`

Comment: Next question: What do you do if `att1` takes values greater than 25? They can't be mapped to a `pch`-value, i.e., a shape.

Comment: The size of the point would handle a continuous variable. Maybe try using the point size instead of color for that attribute. You would want to normalize the sizes to some reasonable range though. Alternatively, you could bin your continuous values into 25 bins, maybe based on quantiles, and use the shape to represent your new binned attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want? [df is your data formatted as above.]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x=X,y=Y,color=factor(att1),shape=att2),size=5)
```

Produces this with your data:

[image]

Comment: Yep. Thanks for the help! ggplot seems to be the way to go.